# MDX - Concatenate level's properties and level's members

Tags: properties, mdx, members, mondrian

I an using mondrian and I have this issue: using a query mdx I need to concatenate in each member name belonging to a certain level, its name and a the value of a certain level properties for that member.

Something like CurrentMember.Name = CurrentMember.Name || CurrentMember.Properties("Prop").

Is this possible in some way?

Thanks.
Matteo

Answer (score 1):

In MDX it should look like that

```
[Dimension].CurrentMember.Name + [Dimension].CurrentMember.Properties("YourProp")
```

The [concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145986.aspx) operator in MDX is `+` not `||`

Comment: Depends on the server! In Mondrian its ||